# Getting "Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/bin/bash' with working directory '/Users/runner/work/...'. No such file or directory

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I keep getting error

```
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/bin/bash' with working directory '/Users/runner/work/java-sdet/java-sdet-bootcamp'. No such file or directory
```

[This is my GitHub Action run](https://github.com/ultimate-qa/java-sdet/actions/runs/4315604347/jobs/7530210265)
This is [the yml](https://github.com/ultimate-qa/java-sdet/blob/main/.github/workflows/2.yml) file I'm trying to use.

Here's a copy of the yml file

```yaml
name: Selenium Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: | 
          cd /Users/runner/work/
          ls -a
          mvn -B package --file pom.xml
        working-directory: /Users/runner/work/java-sdet/java-sdet-bootcamp
      - name: Run tests
        working-directory: java-sdet-bootcamp
        run: mvn test --file pom.xml
```

I've tried different ways to set working-directory. I've tried navigating around using the `cd` command. Nothing is working for me.

Comment: The actual working directory is `/Users/runner/work/java-sdet/java-sdet` and you should use `ls` to learn what's the file system structure there. You cannot set `/Users/runner/work/java-sdet/java-sdet-bootcamp` as working directory if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Made some update and still getting the same issue https://github.com/ultimate-qa/java-sdet/actions/runs/4315857065/jobs/7530823141

Comment: Check your folder name again in github, it has three o's in bootcamp, `java-sdet/java-sdet-boootcamp/`. that's probably the reason for not working

Comment: @Sibtain omg, no way! Thanks so much for catching that. This was the issue!